# Redirecionamento via htacess

Tags: htaccess

Galera, como que faço para redirecionar um site http://www.meuSite.com.br para https://meuSite.com.br utilizando o .htacess.
No provedor que estou ele criou um .htacess dessa forma

```
#DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW SSL_REDIRECT:meuSite.com.br
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meuSite.com.br$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE SSL_REDIRECT:meuSite.com.br
```

Estou meio perdido, e não entendi muito bem como isso funciona. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estou com o SSL Ativo, e não sei se influencia em algo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seusitecomhttps.com.br/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado, mas esses "parametros [R,L] o que significa?

Comment: R|redirect  
S|skip    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: @AndreFirmo Dica: utilize `R=301`. Leitura recomendada: [Redirection](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) (em inglês)